# Why did Kayla hide this photo on the desk?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In *Bombshell* (2019), Kayla saw a photo of Jess Cara on Cara's desk and
decided to hide it:

[image]

> Kayla: Are you crazy?
>
> Jess Cara: What?
>
> Kayla: That's my friend from college.
>
> Jess Cara: I'm just looking out for you.

Why did Kayla hide this photo on the desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did Kayla hide this photo on the desk?

Kayla is "gay*" and it's implied that if this became general knowledge it would adversely affect her career.

<sup>*or appropriate modern term</sup>

Accordingly, whether the photo was "innocent" or actually a photo of Kayla and a girlfriend it could lead to questions Kayla might not want to answer.

Jess is just warning her to take care of possibly "incriminating" photos.